# Does having more memory means my laptop can handle runing mutiple heavy duty software at once?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory

By heavy duty software I mean, runing 2 andriod emulartor like nox/bluestack/LDplayer, photoshop and watching youtube video all at once without ever causing my laptop to slow down.

or more core/ ram the better ??

Comment: You would need to work out how much memory and CPU is required for each thing. Memory will get you so far, more cores will get you so far in another direction, faster cores head in another direction. Getting more of everything is the best option but costs more.

Answer (score 0):

Each program has specific resources it needs to use from your device (RAM, CPU, GPU, HDD/SSD). The more of resources you have, the more programs you can run. Without more specific info on current system specifications and desired programs to be run we cannot answer better than this.

More resources =  better performance.

Comment: "More resources = better performance" _iff that's what was bottlenecking your setup_. Just throwing more resources at a problem does nothing if that problem doesn't need these resources.  I guess that's what you wanted to say in your first sentence, but I feel like it's not clear as it's written now.

Comment: Just based on how the question was written originally I tried to make the answer as simple as possible, but you are correct, it could be any number of things that could be causing a system to slow.

Comment: ... so it'd probably be a good idea to run Task Manager to see which resources are getting hammered on the current computer. I'm no system expert but it seems that'd at least give you a decent idea what add'l resources to concentrate on improving.

Answer (score 0):

> Running 2 andriod emulartor like nox/bluestack/LDplayer, photoshop and
> watching youtube video all at once.

Your question has a couple of questions built into it.

Running emulators or virtual machines requires a good computer.

**(1) Virtual Machines, emulators and regular software**

My laptop has i7 CPU, 16 GB of memory (not expandable) and 1 TB NVMe SSD drive for lots of capacity. It does run 3 Virtual Machines just fine on top of the Host Windows 10 computer with lots of resources to spare.

**(2) Photoshop and graphical software**

Photoshop and like graphical tools often require a good GPU and 32 GB of memory. So that is an additional requirement to consider.

**(3) Web / Internet requirements:**

Watching You Tube Videos and web work requires a fast AC wireless card or good Ethernet. My laptop has an Intel AC card which is very good.

Your ISP has to provide fast Modem speed. A top notch computer with slow Internet is not helpful.  So:

**Laptop:**  Lots of memory, strong CPU, very fast SSD.

**Graphics:**  More memory, better GPU.

**Web:**  Fast ISP and very fast Wireless - maybe even Wi-Fi 6 which is coming.

Comment: So your advice is to buy the best hardware available? I mean, it's not wrong, but not very helpful at the same time. And doesn't answer the question asked, nor help OP bridge the gap in their understanding of the subject.

Comment: The OP wishes to run a lot at once. So the advice was to illustrate what is required. If the current hardware does not measure up (it may not) then it might need to be replaced. So I was saying this is what is needed to answer the question.

Comment: so on my current laptop, i have 8 GB of Memory, and whenever i run 2 android emulator, and watch youtube, it took up 97-99% of my laptop which in turn slows down my laptop (video starts to slow, game start to lag)

Comment: given the requirements - which don't include a budget - getting the best thing is the way to go. I would even prefer a real PC instead of a laptop, which can pack even more horsepower and doesn't scream the fans under load.

Comment: so my question is, will increasing my ram to say 32 GB really have will have much improvement?

Comment: The laptop is not really up to so many simultaneous activities.  You may need to run fewer things until the point you could upgrade the hardware and make sure the internet you have can keep up. Just adding memory, if you can, may help.

Comment: Noted with thanks!

Comment: Thanks. You might wish to upvote my answer and other answers as they cover a lot of the bases.

Answer (score 0):

Processor and ram are going to work hand in hand for heavy loads. Multi-threaded processors like ryzen 5, ryzen 7, or intel i7 will handle heavy loads much better than fewer cores like an i3, or ryzen 3. No amount of ram will be able to make up for that.

That said, even with a ryzen 7, only having 8 gb of ram in a laptop or a desktop will make the system crawl.

- Windows will eat 3gb of that
- Chrome will eat a chunk
- what's left will go to your programs

you want at least 16gb to do most moderate tasks. But if you're doing multiple virtual machines or compositing video, start thinking about 8gb of ram per big task on top of your 16gb. ie., a linux and a windows VM on top of your primary os with a ryzen threadripper? You want 32gb of ram at bare minimum.

Comment: a i5 will also have 4 core. so a i5 with 32 GB be the best combo ? so i can do big task such as watching youtube, having at least 2 android emulator runing without making my laptop crawl?

Comment: See if your laptop can use 32 GB . It might not. I have one i5 machine with fast SSD and 16 GB of memory. It does not lag and I do not think an investment in memory (can be done) will help much. I have an i7 laptop with very fast SSD and 16 GB of memory. It runs 4 machines simultaneously without lagging. It might possibly benefit from more memory but the point is moot as the memory is soldered in . New laptop sometime.